# How do I get Python Script to draw a simple line in Adobe Illustrator and Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, adobe-illustrator

Like the title says, I just can't get Python script to draw a line between two points in Adobe Illustrator.  The following code keeps generating errors:

```
from os import linesep
import win32com.client as win32com

app = win32com.GetActiveObject("Illustrator.Application")
docRef = app.Documents.Add()
app.Documents.Add()

myLine = docRef.PathItems.Add()
myLine.Stroked = True
myLine.StrokeWidth =5

myLine.SetEntirePath([[10.,20.], [30, 70]]) #fails here
```

There are other options that I prefer not to use, due to wanting to learn Python in this process.
VBScript, JavaScript and AppleScript have documentation, but Python has the speed and is recommended because it can handle opening and closing files on my computer.

I have tried just about every permutation of the array inside the line that says:

```
myLine.SetEntirePath([[10.,20.], [30, 70]]) #fails here
```

but nothing works.  Usually I get the error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\User\Documents\code\python_illustrator_api\test_com_interface.py", line 41, in <module>
    myLine.SetEntirePath([[10.,20.], [30, 70]])
  File "<COMObject Add>", line 2, in SetEntirePath
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Adobe Illustrator', 'Illegal argument - argument 1\n- Only arrays with dimension 1 are supported', None, 0, -2147220262), None)     
PS C:\Users\User\Documents\code\python_illustrator_api>
```

This is suggestive that the array is not formatted correctly, but it looks good to me.  I have tried just about every possibility: No square brackets, no outer brackets.  From what I know of Python, this is the correct format for an array with two X,Y pairs to draw a simple line from the two points.

When I try

```
myLine.SetEntirePath([10.,20.], [50., 100.], [100, 30])
```

I get a different error:

```
TypeError: SetEntirePath() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

That is a little more promising, because it seems to be a more descriptive error.  Also, correct me if I'm wrong, but basically, VSCode has no helpful prompting when using Win32com as it talks to an API, right?  Basically, errors can come from Adobe Illustrator, but there are no helpful suggestions like other versions of Visual Studio.

I have also tried using an array using numpy, but that doesn't work either.

```
import numpy as np
array1 = np.array([[20, 50], [30, 70]])
myLine.SetEntirePath(array1)
```

What's the problem?  Is there some kind of misunderstanding between win32com and Illustrator?
This is a really basic thing to do, get a script to draw a line between two points on Illustrator.

I could perhaps draw a line on an open instance of Adobe Illustrator, grab the line-segment using Python script, and then kind of reverse-engineer the format that the API likes to have its arrays sent to it, but that might have it's own problems.

Shouldn't something work?  After all don't all these different languages end up getting processed through the Common Intermediate Language and then send to the API?

Can someone suggest some solution to this?
Thank you in advance

Comment: I removed my answer, since I see no reaction from OP for a couple days and I've promised never answer here unless there is any reaction from OP. Good luck. Let me know if you need the answer at all

Comment: Thank you Yuri for your answer.  I appreciate your excellent response.  I work midnights and only use my laptop occasionally, and don't have my Android connected to this account.  I also am guilty of delaying a response for the sake of hearing from others as well, even though you answered it perfectly.  Once a question gets answered too well, most other people opt out.  Sorry.

Comment: If you find someone’s answer useful you can upvote, accept, or make a comment at the very least. It’s just basic politeness. There can be better answers in the future of course. But only if there still are answerers

Comment: Thanks.  Worked perfectly.  As an aside, I stumbled upon using Python because I wanted to do scripting and looked it up on Youtube (Illustrator/Scripting/Tutorial).  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=38iB2MP1wyw .  But, even though this video exists, all the Adobe documentation is in Javascript/others, not Python.  I would recommend to others to choose a language that is well-documented from the App-maker when they want to write scripts.  For this purpose JavaScript>>Python.  Anyway, sorry for any offense, and cheers.

Comment: Illustrator's API not exactly well documented even for JavaScript (Extendscript, to be precise), not to mention Python. I love Python, but whenever I write Illustrator's script in Python (not that it happens too often, though) I'm actually write it in JS first and then rewrite it in Python. Cheers! )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting. Probably the `SetEntirePath()` method is broken or something, indeed. I didn't manage to get it work with Python as well.

But there is a workaround. `pathItems.pathPoints` collection has the method `Add()`, so you can use a loop to add any points with given coordinates to the path this way:

```
import win32com.client as win32com

app = win32com.GetActiveObject("Illustrator.Application")
doc = app.Documents.Add()

myLine = doc.pathItems.Add()
myLine.stroked = True
myLine.strokeWidth = 5

points = [[10, 20], [50, 100], [100, 30]]
for xy in points:
    point = myLine.pathPoints.Add()
    point.anchor         = xy
    point.leftDirection  = xy
    point.rightDirection = xy
```

Output:

[image]